# Which one is executed in localhost - DispatcherServlet or OncePerRequestFilter?

Tags: spring

I'm hitting an API locally through a Postman.

Which one is executable in localhost - `DispatcherServlet` class or `OncePerRequestFilter` class ?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be.

Comment: Please add some more details and exact problem to get good help.May be add some code with little more detailing.Your question can get closed if it is found too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **What is the use of** `DispatcherServlet` **in Spring MVC ?**

   - The `DispatcherServlet` is a central servlet that helps in dispatching the request to the controllers. It is integrated with Spring IoC (Inversion of Control) Container (which is responsible for managing the life-cycle of the bean). This also provides various functionality for the development of the web applications. It acts as Front Controller for the web application.

**Screenshot of what happens behind scenes in Spring MVC([From Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s02.html)) :**

[image]

2. **What is the use of** `OncePerRequestFilter` **?**

   - It is a class that guarantees the execution of a method based on the request to be allowed, on any servlet container.

**Q : Which one is executable in localhost - DispatcherServlet class or OncePerRequestFilter class ?**

- First the request will be dispatched by the DispatcherServlet. Then, filter will be called because filter acts as wall in between DispatcherServlet and Controllers. If the request meets criteria of the filter, then the request is allowed to hit the particular API. Otherwise, that request is filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation-
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter "guarantees to be just executed once per request". Under what circumstances a Filter may possibly be executed more than once per request?

And it will be executed for the localhost also. It must be executed whenever any request is generated.